# Validate unique properties in an array with Json Schema and AJV

Tags: javascript, node.js, jsonschema, json-schema-validator, ajv

This is the sample data :-

```
"labels": [
            {"name" : "sampleId", "value" : "12345"}, 
            {"name" : "SAMPLEID", "value" : "12345"}
          ]
```

I want the *name* to be unique in this array, I am using draft 2007 for json schema, it does not specify any standard keyword for such use case. I was able to use ajv-keywords as it has one keyword *uniqueItemProperties* which solves the problem to some level the only problem is it does case-insensitive match while according to my use case different cases should be allowed for *name*, is there a way to solve this without writing a custom validator ?

Answer (score 1):

you can use `uniqueItems: true`. This keyword validation compares the two object instances for deep equality. casing would be preserved and would be considered unique.

```json
{
"$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
"type": "object",
"properties": {
    "labels": {
        "type": "array",
        "uniqueItems": true,
        "items": {
             "type": "object",
             "properties": {
                  "name": {
                     "type": "string"
                  },
                  "value": {
                     "type": "string"
                  }
             }
         }
     }
  }
}
```

```js
const Ajv = require('ajv')
const better = require('better-ajv-errors').default
let _ajvOptions = {
    strict: false,
    allErrors: true,
    messages: true
};

const data = {
    "labels": [
        { "name": "sampleId", "value": "12345" },
        { "name": "SAMPLEID", "value": "12345" }
    ]
}


const schema = {
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
    "type": "object",
    "properites": {
        "labels": {
            "type": "array",
            "uniqueItems": true,
            "items": {
                "type": "object",
                "properties": {
                    "name": {
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    "value": {
                        "type": "string"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

try {
    let ajv = new Ajv(_ajvOptions);

    let validate = ajv.compile(schema)


    let results = validate(data)
    console.log(results = {
        valid: results,
        error: better(schema, data, validate.errors, { format: "js", indent: 4 })
    })
} catch (err) {
    console.error(results = {
        valid: false,
        error: err.message,
    })

}
```

Comment: I could not find reference to any "uniqueItems" property in 2007 draft, moreover I want to restrict this uniqueness check just for the "name" key, since I want to invalidate even if "name" fails the uniqueness test and value are different, this implementation would rather pass this case. Thanks for your reply Jeremy :)

Comment: there's no way to limit the uniqueness to a single keyword, it has to be against the entire schema definition (in this case, it would be each object schema at each array index)

Comment: here you can find the JSON Schema reference docs about each keyword.  `uniqueItems` was introduced well before the draft-07 iteration.  https://www.learnjsonschema.com/2020-12/validation/uniqueitems/